# Is there an easy and automatic way of converting a Windows XNA project into a Monotouch Monogame project?

Tags: xna, monotouch, monogame

I have just started with XNA development on Windows. But as I'm a fan of iOS I had to try porting my test code over to Monotouch on the Mac.
I used these instructions: http://www.facepuncher.com/blogs/10parameters/?p=42
But this is so much (manual) work! 
And it really doesn't answer open topics like: why would I copy all the XNB files and in addition all the resources, like PNGs?

Is there maybe a tool that automatically converts a Windows XNA project into a Monotouch iOS project or at least creates the correct folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a magical "Port it!" button that will do everything for you, however [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/) does a pretty good job of getting rid of most of the manual work, while maintaining most of your current code.

Comment: But ExEn is yet another implementation of XNA on iOS. I'd like to stick with Monogame.

Comment: Then I'm not sure you will get a magic port switch that does everything for you.  ExEn uses Monotouch, so it should be similar enough for a basic XNA test project port.

Answer (score 0):

Although this video targets MonoDroid, it's still a good reference and can answer most of your questions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF0sm5KGPPM